# Drop Down Menu in Magento hangs too low and disappears upon movement of the mouth

Tags: css, magento

Our website http://www.oflooring.com , I need to make a change where the main top drop down menu is closer to the main menu. I cannot for the life of me find the code to tweak in order to fix it.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is css on colorstyles.css that should be around line 139 that looks like such.

```
ul#magemenu-top li ul {
    top: 87px;
    background-color: #E4D94F;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

I'm guessing from your question the `top` value is probably what you want to change, like something around `50px` instead of `87px`?

Comment: Thank you 
This worked like a charm 
I appreciate your time and info

Comment: @RJavan if this is the answer you were looking for, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).